# subprocess cp leaves some files empty

Tags: python, macos, subprocess

I'm trying to copy some files from one directory to another. I want all files in one directory to end up in the root of another directory.

This command does exactly what I want when I run it in the terminal:

```
cp -rv ./src/CopyPasteIntoBuildDir/* ./build-root/src/
```

This line of python, however, copies most of the files just like the above command, but it leaves some of the new files empty. Specifically, files in subdirectories are left empty.

```
subprocess.check_call("cp -rv ./src/CopyPasteIntoBuildDir/* ./build-root/src/", shell=True)
```

It creates the files if they're not there, and it truncates them if they are.

What is going on?

Comment: I'd bet on shell argument expansion being the culprit, have you tried: `subprocess.check_call(["cp", "-rv", "./src/CopyPasteIntoBuildDir/*", "./build-root/src/"])` ? Also, you are aware of the [`shutil`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html) module, right?

Comment: @zwer That doesn't work. Pretty sure it's because of the `*`. Shutil doesn't seem to have a "copy everything in this folder and dump it in this other folder" function :( Would have to `os.walk` my way through, and I'm just not reimplementing `cp` like that.

Comment: `os.system("cp -rv ./src/CopyPasteIntoBuildDir/* ./build-root/src/")` has the same result; leaving files in subdirectories empty.

Comment: Python uses sh, and I'm using bash; maybe that's the culprit?

Comment: [`shutil.copytree()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree) copies the entire tree, no need for `os.walk()`.

Comment: @zwer yeah, but I don't want the parent folder of the source; just all of its contents.

Comment: It'd be interesting to review a log of the original issue being reproduced with `sysdig`, `strace -f`, or a similar tool monitoring what's actually going on at the OS layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're decided to use `cp` rather than native Python operations --

This code will be much more reliable if you write it to *not invoke any shell whatsoever*. To avoid the need for `/*` on the source (and the side effects of this -- ie. refusal to copy directories whose names exceed the `ARG_MAX` combined environment and command-line size storage limit), use `.` as the last element of the name of the directory whose contents are to be copied, instead of passing a wildcard that needs to be expanded by a shell.

```
subprocess.check_call(["cp", "-R", "--", '%s/.' % src, dest])
```

The use of `cp -R` rather than `cp -rv` is on account of `-R`, but not `-r`, being POSIX-standardized (and thus portable across all compliant UNIXlike platforms).

---

#### Demonstrating In Action (copy/pasteable code)

```
tempdir=$(mktemp -d -t testdir.XXXXXX)
trap 'rm -rf "$tempdir"' EXIT

cd "$tempdir"
mkdir -p ./src/CopyPasteIntoBuildDir/subdir-1 ./build-root/src/
touch ./src/CopyPasteIntoBuildDir/file-1
touch ./src/CopyPasteIntoBuildDir/subdir-1/file-2

script='
import sys, shutil, subprocess

src = sys.argv[1]
dest = sys.argv[2]
subprocess.check_call(["cp", "-R", "--", "%s/." % src, dest])
'

python -c "$script" ./src/CopyPasteIntoBuildDir ./build-root/src/
find ./build-root -type f -print
rm -rf "$tempdir"
```

...emits output akin to:

```
./build-root/src/file-1
./build-root/src/subdir-1/file-2
```

...showing that content was correctly recursively copied with no prefix.

Answer (score -1):

So apparently this is a problem with `sh`. Using bash instead worked.

```
subprocess.check_call("cp -rv ./src/CopyPasteIntoBuildDir/* ./build-root/src/", shell=True, executable="/bin/bash")
```

**EDIT: See accepted answer!**

Comment: That's very difficult to believe. `cp` is not part of *either* `sh` or `bash` -- you get the same implementation, that being the one in `/bin` or `/usr/bin` provided by your OS vendor, no matter which shell invokes it. (The only exceptions are places where `/bin/sh` is busybox, but in such environments `/bin/cp` will typically *also* be busybox).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - there is a distant possibility of `sh` on his system having an alias set for `cp`...

Comment: @zwer, ...only if there's an environment variable named `ENV` pointing to a script that establishes such an alias (and the copy of `/bin/sh` actually supports aliases in noninteractive shells, which is unusual). Otherwise, dotfiles aren't read in noninteractive shells started with `sh -c '...'` (as `subprocess.check_call()` invokes with `shell=True`, with the code passed in the `...` argument), so there's no possible way for an alias to be defined.

Comment: @zwer, ...granted, `/bin/bash` will honor `BASH_ENV` rather than `ENV` as a script to read at initialization time, and *those* could be updating the `PATH` to include a location with a different version of `cp`, but again, that's all very unusual -- I can count the number of times I've seen `ENV` or `BASH_ENV` used intentionally (as opposed to, say, using `ENV` to distinguish between dev and production environments, not knowing that the variable has a meaning that modifies behavior of noninteractive shells) on one hand.

Comment: @zwer, ...`bash` will also honor exported functions, which `sh` won't unless it's provided by bash -- but if the problem were an exported function shadowing the `cp` command then we'd expect standard-compliant `cp` behavior with `/bin/sh`, and nonconformant behavior with `bash`. Which is to say, bottom-line, imagining a case where the behavior differs as described here requires going very far out on some unlikely limbs, and is unlikely to be helpful to other people with the same problem.

Comment: Switched to the other answer now, using `.` instead of `*`. I'm still a bit curious why using bash helped. Also, I only have 3 files in the directory at the moment, so hitting ARG_MAX seems unlikely.

Comment: try to use rsync , which might  help

Comment: I'd like to know (why using bash appeared to fix this for you) too. See https://gist.github.com/charles-dyfis-net/c96e6b4a57c44ced858c414ca4c8c22d for a test case showing your original code (only the paths changed) working correctly (all output-directory files containing content, none of them empty). If you could build a reproducer that worked for others (showcasing the problem), it would certainly help the question make more sense.